# OSMC / Raspberry Pi 2 dual display w/ HDMI and Raspberry Pi Touch Screen Display

Tags: pi-2, hdmi, display, osmc, dsi

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 setup with OSMC media center running. It works great. I can use either HDMI or the 7" Raspberry Pi Touch Screen Display. With one display or the other it works great!

However, I'm trying to build a setup for in the car that has multiple screens. Is there a way to configure OSMC on the Raspberry Pi 2 to mirror the display to both the HDMI output and Raspberry Pi Touch Screen Display (using the DSI connector) at the same time?

Comment: I never used or even thought about dual screen, but I did some research and found out there isn't a way to do it on osmc. Check this link out: http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=255005

Comment: I am looking to do the very same, would be great if someone had the answer to this.